# Am I protected over the internet with ubuntu, do I need an antivirus?

Tags: internet, password, email, antivirus

I know that Ubuntu is secure, but I'm worried about my passwords when I login to my yahoo email, or my facebook. Do I need an antivirus on Ubuntu to be password protected when navigating over the internet?

Comment: Even though the program is mildly depricated, it still works very well. It doesn't auto-remove anything. But, it lets you know of changes that have been made to your file system. Read up on a program called *tripwire* and *AIDE*